# Passing the response of one API call to another API

Tags: node.js, request, async.js

I have two urls which will add the new user and edit the user sequentially. How can I pass the output of first request to the second request as input.

```
http://localhost:3010/postuser
{"name":"xyz"}
// response will be unique id =>001

http://localhost:3010/putuser
{"id":001} //Get the output of first request as input here
```

Below is my code

```
function httpGet(options, callback) {
    request(options,
        function (err, res, body) {
            callback(err, body);
        }
    );
}
const urls = [
    {
        url: 'http://localhost:3010/postuser',
        method: 'POST'
    },
     {
        url: 'http://localhost:3010/putuser',
        method: 'PUT'
    }
];
async.mapSeries(urls, httpGet, function (err, res) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: If anyone knows the answer, post your comments or answer, instead of down voting it

Answer (score 1):

Use [async.waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) so that data from one function can be passed to next function. Check the example in the [link](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall). So essentially you will call httpGet function and pass the data received from API1 to next function using callback. Then you can call the API2.